# listitem of list in wpf without bullet

Tags: wpf, list, button, listitem

i am new in wpf and i have a list as like

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="fdsvList" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
                        xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalScrollBarVisibility='Auto'>
            <FlowDocument>
                <List Name="lstButton">
                    <ListItem Margin="0 0 0 10" Name="lstItmCheck">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Button Content="{DynamicResource Visa}" Name="btnVisa" Click="btnVisa_Click">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="None">
                                                <ContentPresenter />
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

it display with the bullet list.

but i don't want bullet in list, i just want simple button without bullet.

How can i do. please help me.

Comment: Why are you using a FlowDocument as the container?

Comment: i just put my sample code here....can it effect it list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
<List Name="lstButton" MarkerStyle="None">
```

You can also do this in the designer, via the properties panel.